# Angular2 - Detect Changes of Attribute @Input

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-changedetection

I have a simple Attribute Directive `mask`, with an `@Input() mask:string`

I want to be able to detect and react to changes on the `mask` binding
I can use `ngOnChanges` somehow, but I feel like this is like painting the problem with a large brush

Sample/Simplified code of directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'mask'
})
export class MaskDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input() mask: string;

  constructor(public el: ElementRef) {};

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    $(this.el.nativeElement).mask(this.mask);
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
<input type='text' [mask]='someBinding'>
```

When the value of `someBinding` changes, how to execute some code, without relying on `ngChanges` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use setter method for `mask` property instead of more broad `ngOnChanges`:

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'mask'
})
export class MaskDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input set mask(newValue: string) {
    $(this.el.nativeElement).mask(newValue);
  }

  constructor(public el: ElementRef) {};


}
```

Setter is going to be more efficient as it's related to only this property.

Comment: Thanks for your reply; It'd be great if it'd work but then I get a `duplicate identifier 'mask'` error. Did you actually managed to do this so it works or? Ideas?

Comment: Never mind that - Your solution works, except you need to decorate the setter itself with the @Input decorator

I sent an edit with the fix

Thanks!